# Why both MAC and IP Address on a packet?

Tags: networking

Why do we need the information of source ip address and source mac address in a packet when one of them is sufficient for identification of source? Are they required for all protocols?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention "in a packet". I wanted to know at the time of packet transfer from source to destination. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC addresses are layer-2 addresses, IP addresses are layer-3 addresses, and ports are layer-4 addresses.

MAC addresses are not in the packet headers, they are in the frame headers. Only layer-3 addresses are in the packet headers. Ports are in the segment headers.

MAC addresses are only significant on a LAN. They are in the frame headers, and frames are stripped at layer-3 boundaries (routers). The routers then use the layer-3 headers with the layer-3 address to forward a packet to the next interface, where the router will build a new layer-2 frame with new layer-2 addresses for the new layer-2 link.

Answer (score 0):

Within a network only the IP address is sufficient. But within different networks, the router needs to resolve IP address based on the MAC address. IP address can vary but the MAC address is constant. A machine can connect to another machine through physical address i.e. MAC.

For most of the TCP/IP protocols you need both.

Comment: IP doesn't need MAC addresses. IP can run on many layer-2 protocols, some of which don't use MAC addresses. Within an ethernet network (LAN), you most certainly need MAC addresses since that is how the ethernet frame is delivered to the destination. Also, MAC addresses will not be seen on a different network.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But for layman language, it is difficult to understand layer wise concept. So I gave a generalized answer which is the TCP/IP protocol suite.

Comment: The problem is that what you wrote is wrong and misleading. Anyone doing network programming needs to completely understand how the layers work, and layman language really has no place on a programmers site.

Comment: Edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need the source IP address, As the reply will come to that. This will remain constant in the packet through out its travel. This need not be a valid one also. (Like in case of IP address Spoofing.)

The source mac address will be required for the next hop (router), not beyond that. If the next hop is seeing you for the first time, It'll update its routing table accordingly using your IP address and MAC address.

If the next hop is unable to resolve the destination IP address or unable to find a path, it will decide to drop the packet and will notify you the same. But if it finds a path and forwards the packet, then it'll replace its own MAC address at the source MAC address field. But the source IP address remains unchanged in this case. (It'll also change in case of a proxy.)